# Start using a standard keyboard layout (same on all platforms)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, layout

I am willing to start using the US layout on all my computers for some reasons such as:

1. Being more 'universal', it will be for sure available in all computers.
2. Being better for programming than the Spanish layout, because it has most useful symbols in better places, like []{}'"/ and so on.
3. Being it impossible to program in vim out of the box on any computer without remapping all keys (in the Spanish one).

I am now on my macbook and found very satisfying to use two layouts I found:

- US (for programming)
- US - International - PC (for typing in Spanish, thanks to the dead keys)

BUT, I found two big problems:

1. There are some **differences** between OS X versions of these layouts and the PC versions.
2. The apple version has some weird keys (related to above). For example, left to the "1" key, there is this symbol -> "§". And I can not find a layout in my settings which has the typical "~" symbol, indeed I cannot even find that symbol!, only this one "˜".

I guess that some of these problems are related to the fact that typical US keyboards have large shift key and short enter key, whereas Spanish one has the opposite, having "`" key next to "z" and "\" in the middle line.

So my question is, what should I do to have an standard US layout in all my computers? Should I just stick to the PC version and make a custom layout on my apple laptop?

Comment: have a look at the different English layouts on https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201794 [Note the US keyboard is just rather self-centredly called "English"] The US layout has a 'short' return key & doesn't have any key next to z. I'd rely on mapping to which your *actual* keyboard is closest to, rather than the US, which is pretty much unique.

Comment: The problem is that I still can´t find one that matches the US position of the symbols and still mantain consistence with both OSX and PC.
The main problem is the -->`~<-- key, which is next to z in Apple and next to 1 in PC. I don't want to have this inconsistences.

Comment: My PC keyboard has tilde ~ way over to the right of 890-=...  on shifted # just left of the backspace key ... so no, there's no consistency at all. Pick the closest to what you have.